# In VisualStudio DTE, how to get the contents of the ActiveDocument?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

I'm scripting inside VisualStudio and am trying to get the contents of the currently ActiveDocument.

This is my current solution:

```
var visualStudio = new API_VisualStudio_2010();

var vsDTE = visualStudio.VsAddIn.VS_Dte;

var document = (Document)vsDTE.ActiveDocument;
var textDocument = (TextDocument)document.Object("TextDocument");

var editPoint = textDocument.StartPoint.CreateEditPoint();
var text = editPoint.GetText(textDocument.EndPoint.CreateEditPoint());

panel.clear().add_SourceCodeViewer()
     .set_Text(text,  document.FullName.extension());
```

Is this the best way?

I got the solution from: [Because ActiveDocument.Text() Would Be Too Easy...](http://ask.metafilter.com/103284/Because-ActiveDocumentText-Would-Be-Too-Easy)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is working for me

```
protected DTE2 dte;
dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));

public string GetCurrentTextFile(){

  TextDocument doc = (TextDocument)(dte.ActiveDocument.Object("TextDocument"));
  var p = doc.StartPoint.CreateEditPoint();
  string s = p.GetText(doc.EndPoint);

  return s;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a try?

```
Dim objSelection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
```

Comment: That only gets the current selected text: 

var vsDTE = visualStudio.VsAddIn.VS_Dte;

var textSelection  = (TextSelection)vsDTE.ActiveDocument.Selection;
return textSelection;