# Run script when finished saving file - Visual Studio Extensibility

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

Can someone give me some sample code for Visual Studio Extensibility where I can grab the text from a document, when the Save event ends, and run a script in C # with that text (example, trigger a Web service for certain file extensions). It could also be a new button (for example, save in the web service).

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the **DocumentSaved** event:

```
    events = DTE.Events;
    documentEvents = events.DocumentEvents;
    documentEvents.DocumentSaved += OnDocumentSaved;
```

In the OnDocumentSaved handler with EnvDTE.Document you can get the document path as **doc.FullName**.

To get text from EnvDTE.Document:

```
  TextDocument td = (TextDocument)(doc.Object("TextDocument"));
  var p = td.StartPoint.CreateEditPoint();
  string s = p.GetText(td.EndPoint);
```

See [In VisualStudio DTE, how to get the contents of the ActiveDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606274/in-visualstudio-dte-how-to-get-the-contents-of-the-activedocument) and https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html for complete samples.

Comment: @Luis Medeiros, Could you get useful information from Sergey's suggestion? Do you resolve this issue?