# How to do action in Visual Studio when a file type is saved

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Each time a JavaScript file is saved in Visual Studio, I want to be able to run a code that gets the file path as the input parameter, analyzes the file, and does some operations on it based on the content of that JavaScript file and its location.

I thought of creating an extension, and automating this process. But that's too much work. And its deployment to team members is also a pain.

Is there an easier way to hook into OS operations through Visual Studio?

Comment: maybe write an external program and use `FileSystemWatcher`

Comment: @DaveCousineau, I thought about that. But it gets very tricky. The program should run silently, and also a huge amount of configuration is needed to filter watching process to a limited set of files, in specific directories, and distribution might become a killer.

Comment: What about a pre-build command? It wouldn't be every time the file is saved though.

Comment: @john, that's not the case. Saving occurs usually way less than building.

Comment: maybe you're looking for something like the T4 templates? a code file that generates code files?

Comment: @DaveCousineau, no, I just want to hook into the save event of files, from *within* Visual Studio. I know I can develop extensions for that. But I'm searching for a simpler way, if at all. Something like *post-build*, but for file saving, something that might be called **post-save**

Comment: imho the only way would be via a VS plugin

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49268744/run-script-when-finished-saving-file-visual-studio-extensibility and https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#OnDocumentSaved